# Refiner value is not populated in Refiners tab of Search Results Web Part

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search, refiner

I have created a site column called "mySiteCol1" and performed search such that this column must be populated in the Refiners tab on Search Results Web Part and I can filter the search results.But the column itself is not populated in this tab. What may be the issue that, this site column is not populated? I have already performed full crawl,checked the checkbox for Refineable and sortable and generated managed properties. Any extra configuration do I need to add in the search schema or search results web part.

Answer (score 1):

In order for properties to show up in the Refiners you'll have to make sure that the Managed Property has at least `Queriable` checked and `Refineable` set to *Yes - active*.

Also make sure to update the Refiner webpart on the search page to include this Managed Property.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.Yes, all the steps you have mentioned is been configured. Its perfectly working in my dev and test environment but when I configured the same in customers UAT environment, this site column did not show up in the refiners list box under the Refiners tab.

Comment: am not getting your suggestion, "Also make sure to update the Refiner web part on the search page to include this Managed Property." Why should I update the Refiner web part, if I am not using refiner web part in my search results page.I am using Search Results Web Part only.

Comment: Is there data in the column?

Comment: @Mathew, Thanks for your reply. No there is no data in this column.

Answer (score 0):

Do you check Searchable for managed property?

Is your managed property mapped to crawled property of **mySiteCol1**?

Are search results you get related to the value of the managed property? Refiner value only is shown up when having relation with search results.